# How would i go about setting up QoS on my router (D-Link DSL-2877AL)? I'm a bit overwhelmed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

i'm looking to enable QoS for my PC. I live in a house where lots of video is being streamed nearly all day, and the only time that i am able to play my Overwatch with ping that is under 300ms is either very late at night/ early morning (~1am-7am), when housemates are out, or when i use my mobile data to play (which i've been doing for the past few weeks, very costly!)

I looked into it and learned about QoS, and saw my router supports it. So i open the router settings, find QoS, and... i have no clue what to do.

I have very basic network knowledge from when I did ICT (Static IP's, Ports, DMZ = bad, etc) but this is next level for me. I'd appreciate any help.

[image: photo of router settings]

Comment: QoS is best applied to outbound traffic. At the top of the settings page you can see it only applies to upstream (presumably meaning outbound traffic) on your router. It won’t help solve your lag/latency issues.

Comment: Reading you router's manual would be a good start. Or clicking on that `More...` link in the help pane.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few hurdles to overcome. QoS is a poorly understood and poorly documented concept. Often enough the download QoS doesn't work as expected (it says on that page that qos is for upload on that router)

You need to be able to set a global speed limit, i don't see one on that page. That's your first step, in the unlikely event that you  can get this to work.

If you really want to go down this rabbit hole, i'd go to tomato-shibby or edgerouter's sqm.